# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Lightweight PDF viewer to navigate through files in a folder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14886/lightweight-pdf-viewer-to-navigate-through-files-in-a-folder)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Web service to detect whether a picture has been published on the Internet before or not, very fast](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/web-service-to-detect-whether-a-picture-has-been-published-on-the-internet-befor)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [PGP software for Windows 7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/pgp-software-for-windows-7)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Windows Software to access Linux partitions from Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/windows-software-to-access-linux-partitions-from-windows)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Can you convert html, css and javascript into a exe?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Version control system for closed source project](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/version-control-system-for-closed-source-project)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [How can I identify the time offset between two similar, but materially different, MP3 files?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14954/how-can-i-identify-the-time-offset-between-two-similar-but-materially-different)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 11)

---

- [Libraries for identifying the face structure](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16223/libraries-for-identifying-the-face-structure)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 11)

---

- [Knowledge management and e-learning software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/knowledge-management-and-e-learning-software)

**Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

- [Freeware online store?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16272/freeware-online-store)

**Net Score: -13** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 14)

---